# Pitch accent of ～ちまう and ～ちゃう

Tags: pitch-accent, auxiliaries

The pitch accent of ～てしまう is fairly obvious. The pitch accent of the て-form is well-documented and しまう is just a 平板 verb.

As for the contracted forms ～ちまう and ～ちゃう, I have come across conflicting information both online as well as in my personal observations.

What is the resulting pitch accent when one appends ～ちまう and ～ちゃう to 平板 (する, 言う, 寝る) and 起伏 (来る, 持つ, 食べる) verbs?

Comment: I can't think of a case where 〜てしまう and 〜ちゃう or 〜ちまう have different accents. Have you actually come across such a case?

Comment: @aguijonazo I think I've heard people say しちゃ＼う before (albeit less often than しちゃう￣). してしまう OTOH is always flat.

Comment: Not sure but it could have been due to sentence-level intonation.

Comment: To me, I think it normally goes down? Regarding the "fairly obvious" and "well-documented", I think it would be good if you specified how the pitch accent is instead.